# React native persist and encrypt user token - Redux-persist-transform-encrypt error

Tags: encryption, react-native, redux, asyncstorage

It seems there is an issue using the encrypt option of redux-persist in react-native:

https://github.com/maxdeviant/redux-persist-transform-encrypt/issues/15

Can anyone help with any solution/workaround to use redux persist to encrypt and store a login token in react-native?

When I try to use the redux persist with the redux-persist-transform-encrypt i get 
`Redux-persist-transform-encrypt: expected outbound state to be a string error`

```
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { persistStore, autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import createEncryptor from 'redux-persist-transform-encrypt';
import reducers from './reducers';


const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  {},
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk),
    autoRehydrate(),
  ),
);

const encryptor = createEncryptor({
  secretKey: 'my-super-secret-key-999',
});


persistStore(
  store,
  {
    storage: AsyncStorage,
    whitelist: ['auth'],
    transforms: [encryptor],
  },
);
export default store;
```

My auth state is something like this:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  user: null,
  token: ''
};
```

Is there any solution to use redux-persist-transform encrypt or the transform and other package to encrypt the token when using redux persist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution using the customTransform instead of redux-persist-transform-encrypt:

```
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { persistStore, createTransform, autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
import reducers from './reducers';


const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  {},
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk),
    autoRehydrate(),
  ),
);

const encrypt = createTransform(
  (inboundState, key) => {
    if (!inboundState) return inboundState;
    const cryptedText = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(inboundState), 'secret key 123');

    return cryptedText.toString(); 
  },
  (outboundState, key) => {
    if (!outboundState) return outboundState;
    const bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(outboundState, 'secret key 123');
    const decrypted = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

    return JSON.parse(decrypted);
  },
);

persistStore(
  store,
  {
    storage: AsyncStorage,
    whitelist: ['auth'], // <-- keys from state that should be persisted
    transforms: [encrypt],
  },
);
export default store;
```

When using redux-persist initial state is triggered before rehydrating is finished so I had to apply this too:

https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/master/docs/recipes.md#delay-render-until-rehydration-complete

Comment: From the above code, i am getting error:
Native crypto module could not be used to get secure random number. 
My understanding: CryptoJS does not run in environments without a native crypto module. Can you please help how is it working for you in react native env.

Comment: Your issue is related to recent versions of crypto-js. A possible fix for your issue could be to use  "crypto-js": "3.3.0". More info about your issue here: https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/issues/256

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import createEncryptor from 'redux-persist-transform-encrypt';

import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import rootReducer from '/path/to/your/rootReducer';

const encryptor = createEncryptor({
  secretKey: 'omg-this-is-some-secret-stuff',
});

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  transforms: [encryptor],
};

const reducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store = createStore(reducer);
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

Comment: How to check the encrypted value?

Comment: @HemantKaushik I don't know about that. I'm bit curious why you would like to do that?

Comment: I want to check the shape of data after encryption. In Android, I found it is like a json with string keys and encrypted values and this json is stored in a database.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is working fine and store data in session storage.
Use below to encript redux data.
1) install redux-persist-transform-encrypt module
yarn add redux-persist-transform-encrypt
npm install redux-persist-transform-encrypt --save
2) import redux files.
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import createEncryptor from 'redux-persist-transform-encrypt';
import storageSession from 'redux-persist/lib/storage/session';// store data in session storage
// import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'; // store data in local storage
import promise from 'redux-promise';
import rootReducer from './path/reducers/';
const encryptor = createEncryptor({
  secretKey: 'test@key12',
});
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage:storageSession,
  // storage:storage,
  transforms: [encryptor],
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

export default () => {
  let store = createStore(persistedReducer)
  let persistor = persistStore(store)
  return { store, persistor }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

I create a file `encryptionTransform.js`

```
var CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
import {createTransform} from 'redux-persist';

const secureRandomKey = 'd5552d588d8c5b088f033296fffb7314';

// Custom encryption transform
const encryptionTransform = createTransform(
// Transform state on its way to being serialized and stored
(inboundState, key) => {
const jsonString = JSON.stringify(inboundState);
const encryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
  jsonString,
  secureRandomKey,
).toString();
return encryptedData;
},
// Transform state being rehydrated
 (outboundState, key) => {
 const bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(outboundState, secureRandomKey);
 console.log('bytes :====== ', bytes);
 const decryptedData = JSON.parse(bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
 console.log('decryptedData :====== ', decryptedData);

 return decryptedData;
 },
);

export default encryptionTransform;
```

then import to my store

```
const persistConfig = {
  version: 0,
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: persistWhitelist,
  timeout: 10000,
  transforms: [encryptionTransform],
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);
```